# SQL "with" clause vs inner join (select...)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a simple [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63655/11/0) to try to easier illustrate my problem.

Considering the following database structure:

```
create table cities (id int, name varchar(100), state varchar(2), population int);
create table citizens (id int, name varchar(100), age int, cityId int);

insert into cities values (1, 'Dallas', 'TX', 100);
insert into cities values (2, 'Houston', 'TX', 200);

insert into citizens values (1, 'John', 20, 1); --Dallas
insert into citizens values (2, 'Peter', 30, 1); --Dallas
insert into citizens values (3, 'Paul', 40, 2); --Houston
insert into citizens values (4, 'Steven', 50, 2); --Houston
```

If I want to select the sum of all Texas cities populations **and** the average age of its citizens, I would firstly do something like:

```
select sum(cities.population), avg(citizens.age)
from cities
inner join citizens on citizens.cityId = cities.id
where cities.state = 'TX'
```

It returns `600` and `35`. The average age is correct, but the sum of the population is not. This because, for each city, it returns two lines, one for each citizen, which ends up doubling the correct result that would be `300`.

I came up with two different solutions for this problem, and I want to know the "best" of them, or the more recommended one (i.e. the one that performs the better) - or even another solution, if anyone could suggest me one.

#1 solution

```
select sum(cities.population), avg(citizens.age)
from cities
inner join (select cityId, avg(age) as age from citizens group by cityId) as citizens 
on citizens.cityId = cities.id
where cities.state = 'TX'
```

#2 solution

```
with temp as
(select cityId, avg(age) as age from citizens group by cityId)

select sum(cities.population), avg(temp.age)
from cities
inner join temp on temp.cityId = cities.id
where cities.state = 'TX'
```

It seems to me (and I can be totally wrong about it) that with `with` clause it first selects the entire `citizens` table, creating a temporary table with the result, and then executes the main select (above), joining with this temporary table. But I'm not sure about the `inner join (select...)` in the #1 solution.

**Note**: it's for a Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Use DISTINCT keyword on your first query?

Comment: In terms of optimisation, I think the With clause (what we call a Common Table Expression CTE) is pretty much the same as the inner join (Select ...) version in terms of what actually happens behind the scenes. The With syntax is just more useful if you are going to reference the CTE more than once

Comment: @codeulike It's not "pretty much the same" it is **exactly** the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is close but doesn't produce the correct results -- the average of averages is not the overall average.  Instead, use `sum()` and `count()` and manually calculate the average.

The second problem is that cities with no citizens (if there are any) would be filtered out.  So, I would suggest:

```
select sum(c.population), sum(cz.sum_age) / sum(cz.cnt)
from cities c left join
     (select cityId, sum(age) as sum_age, count(*) as cnt
      from citizens cz
      group by cz.cityId
     ) cz 
     on cz.cityId = c.id
where c.state = 'TX';
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to what Gordon is saying, a CTE in a `WITH` block emphatically does *not* act as a temporary table. It is exactly the same as placing it directly in the query as a derived table.

You can see this by comparing the query plans. The compiler does not see the CTE as anything other than another way of placing a derived table/subquery, and will optimize it in any way possible. You are very unlikely to see the exact setup of a CTE in a Table Spool in the query plan.

There is one further construct that you have not used: an `APPLY`:

```sql
select sum(c.population), sum(cz.sum_age) / sum(cz.cnt)
from cities c
outer apply    -- or cross apply
     (select cityId, sum(age) as sum_age, count(*) as cnt
      from citizens cz
     where cz.cityId = c.id
      group by ()
     ) cz 
where c.state = 'TX';
```

Formulated this way, the summing is conceptually over a single lookup of the `citizens` table.

However, the compiler can usually transform the `join` and `apply` forms to each other, and will pick the best one, so it usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

> I came up with two different solutions for this problem, and I want to
> know the "best" of them, or the more recommended one (i.e. the one
> that performs the better) - or even another solution, if anyone could
> suggest me one.

If it were me, I'd do two separate queries, because you are basically trying to calculate two different aggregates from two different scopes - city and citizen. Might as well be two queries, its a lot easier to read.

```
select sum(cities.population)
from cities
where cities.state = 'TX'

select avg(citizens.age)
from cities
inner join citizens on citizens.cityId = cities.id
where cities.state = 'TX'
```